# Return shared column value when 2 different rows meet my requirements

Tags: mysql

Having a hard time communicating this question in the search to find what I need. Seems like this should be simple, but I'm not well educated with SQL yet. What I have is 3 tables that I am joining together to link all Parameters with Job Ids. From that, I want to return the Job.ID if 2 Parameters are found with the criteria below.

Here is an example of what the tables look like, and below that the criteria:

```
Table1: Job  
Id | Name | ContextId  
1 | Test1 | 1111  
2 | Test2 | 2222  
3 | Test3 | 3333  

Table2: Job2Param  
ContextId | ParamId  
1111 | 120  
1111 | 140  
1111 | 160  
2222 | 220  
2222 | 240  
3333 | 300  

Table3: Param   
ParamId | Name | Value  
120 | User | Brian@gmail.com  
140 | Pwd | P@ssword  
160 | Var | Null  
220 | User | Peter@gmail.com  
240 | PW | passw0rd123  
300 | non | eek

***MASTER TABLE: ALL JOINED  ***  
Id | Name | ContextId | ParamId | Name | Value  
1 | Test1 | 1111 | 120 | User | Brian@gmail.com  
1 | Test1 | 1111 | 140 | Pwd | P@ssword  
1 | Test1 | 1111 | 160 | Var | Null  
2 | Test2 | 2222 | 220 | User | Peter@gmail.com  
2 | Test2 | 2222 | 240 | PW | passw0rd123  
3 | Test3 | 3333 | 300 | non | eek
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is...**For every distinct J.Id:**

- If any P.Value like '%@gmail.com'
- and any other P.Name in ('Password','Pwd','PW')

So what I want the result to be is Job IDs # 1 & 2 since they both have a Parameter value that contains @gmail.com, and both have a different parameter name that contains something that resemblances a password.

How would I go about this?

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.ID

  FROM (SELECT B.CONTEXTID
          FROM PARAM     A
             , JOB2PARAM B
         WHERE A.NAME   IN ('Password', 'Pwd', 'PW')
           AND B.PARAMID = A.PARAMID
       )  A

     , (SELECT B.CONTEXTID
          FROM PARAM     A
             , JOB2PARAM B
         WHERE A.VALUE LIKE '%@gmail.com'
           AND B.PARAMID   = A.PARAMID
       )  B

    , JOB C

 WHERE B.CONTEXTID = A.CONTEXTID
   AND C.CONTEXTID = B.CONTEXTID
;
```